# SQL Server 2008: Recursive iteration how-to

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Imagine a Table named `Group`, each group can have 'child' groups as long as they're of lower 'level'. So there is one-to-many relationship between `Group and childGroup` table.

[image]

There is also a `many-to-many` relation between `Group` and `Items` so `Groups_Items` is used to hold the FK of each table.

I need to write a query where for a `given Group key`, i should `find all its child` groups, `all the childs of child groups`, and all `the customers belonging to those found groups`.

I know it needs to be a recursive query of some sort but i have no idea how this can be done in SQL. Below is the structure of the tables discussed:

[image]

so if i had these data set in the above tables:

[image]

And the query was to find `For Group 1, find Its customers, Its Child groups (and their Childs) and all their customers`, the output should be:

```
<Group> 1
    <customer> 1
    <customer> 2
    <Group> 2
        <customer> 2
        <Group> 3
        <Group> 4
```

Can someone please show me how this can be done? thanks

Comment: If the second grid displays the relationship between `Group` and `childGroup`, then it doesn't look one-to-many to me. Two children share the same parent: `(2, 3)`, `(2, 4)`. Two parents share the same child: `(2, 4)`, `(3, 4)`. That is certainly many-to-many.

Comment: @AndriyM i updated the question with the schema i have now - I just need to able to store the childs of a group so childGroup needs to be One-To-Many where a group can have any number of Childs and each Child has one parent. do you think my schema is wrong concerning Groups and childGroup table relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question

```
;WITH Hierarchy (GroupID,ID,  ParentID
               ,hLevel
               ) AS
(
   -- Base case
   (
   Select  [Parent Key] as GroupID,NULL,NULL,0
   FROM Tree
   where [Parent Key]=1
   UNION
   SELECT
      [Child Key] as GroupID,
      [Child Key] as ID,
      [Parent Key] as ParentID
      ,1 as hLevel
   FROM Tree
   where [Parent Key]=1
   ) 

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive step
   SELECT
      e.[Child Key] as GroupID,
      e.[Child Key],
      e.[Parent Key]
     ,eh.hLevel + 1
   FROM tree e
      INNER JOIN Hierarchy eh ON
         e.[Parent Key] = eh.ID
)


Select Distinct h.GroupID, c.Name,h.ParentID as ParentGroupID
from Hierarchy h
left join test c on h.GroupID=c.ID
```

an older attempt would be

```
Declare @Parent int
Declare @count int
Select @Parent=??

Select cast(ID as Int) as ID
into #tmp
from Tabelle where ParentID=@Parent

select @Count=0
While @Count<(Select Count(*) from #tmp)
   begin
   Select @Count=(Select Count(*) from #tmp)
   insert into #tmp Select Cast(ID as int) from Tabelle where ParentID in (Select ID from #tmp) and ID not in (Select ID from #tmp)
   end
Select * from #tmp
Drop table #tmp
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am not clear on how the recursive part will iterate through the child groups of a given group which themselves can have child group of their own . For example Group ID 1 has Group ID 2 as child, group ID 2 has Group ID 3 and 4 as childs. the WITH syntax is really useful but i am not able to make it work to iterate all child groups (and child group child groups) .

Comment: what is missing if you query SELECT Distinct *
FROM Hierarchy h

Comment: Thanks again -  Couple of questions - 1) normally to get child groups of a say Group 1 would have to do `select *  from Groups join ChildGroups on Groups.key = childGroup.key where Groups.key =1` , is this being done in your code? 2) is `Tree` meant to be `Groups`? .

Comment: i updated the original question and clarified few things. can you please see if your query still holds ? thanks

Comment: I did a modification again, I don't hope you are expection output in displayed format, the results structure should enable you reporting it as desired.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19393/discussion-between-techventure-and-bummi)

Comment: you are wellcome, like puzzles.

Comment: I just noticed that the solution assumes that a Group always has Child Group! But what if a Group has no Child Groups at all and instead it just has Customers ? I think the current solution returns 0 rows in such cases.